# How to pre populate the order summary on PayPal without having multiple buttons?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, paypal

I want to include a PayPal "Buy Now" button on my website and I wondered if it was possible to pre populate the order summary based on the info fetched from a database?

Is it possible to do that without having a cart?

Thanks!

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried yet

Answer (score 0):

Open a popup on clicking the PayPal button(This will be just a image of PayPal button) and show your order summary in it and then inside that popup just make that PayPal buy button(which will have the code for Payment,you can name it "Continue").